# does surjectivity between same space implies injectivity?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If I have a surjective morphism between from a topological space to itself (let's take $S^n$ as an example) does that implies that's is injective?
To show something like that I'd usally use the thoerem that says that if $f:S^n\to S^n$ then
$$\dim(S^n)=\dim(\ker (f))+\dim(\text{Im}(f))$$
but in this case I can't see how it could be helpfull

Edit: I forgot to say that I'm sticking to real spaces

Edit2 [context]:I want to show that if I get a map $f$ without fixed point from $S^2$ to $S^2$ this one is homotopic to the map $\alpha:S^2\to S^2$ with $x\mapsto -x$.
Since if a map that's not surjective has a fixed point, I'm forced to use surjective map. If I can show that $f$ is also injective ,than it's an automorphism and after that I'm done.
Is there a way to show that?

Comment: No. Let $f: \mathbb{N} \to  \mathbb{N} $ be $f((x_1,x_2,...)) = (x_2,x_3,...)$.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm kinda doubting everything I say at this point, but i think that the $f$ you gave me is injective and not surjective.
I'm in the opposite situation

Comment: I'm not sure about the formula $\dim S^n=\dim(\ker f)+\dim(\mbox{Im}f)$. The formula holds for linear maps between vector spaces, but where does your come from? Is it about the topological dimension?

Comment: $f\colon S^1\to S^1,\,z\mapsto z^2$ or even easier but not a spheres example, $f\colon \Bbb R\to\Bbb R,\, x\mapsto x^3-x$.

Comment: In general, you can have a degree $k$ map from $S^n \to S^n$.

Comment: @Alessandro There is a similar formula for Lebesgue dim. with some assumptions satisfied by all compact metric spaces (namely you want a closed map between a normal space and a paracompact one) saying that if $f:X\to Y$ and $\dim(f^{-1}(y))\leq k$ for all $y\in Y$, then $\dim X\leq\dim Y+k$. Of course this tells us nothing here since the usual degree $k$ maps of spheres have zero dimensional fibers.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Thank you, I didn't know this result for Lebsgue dimension.

Comment: @Alessandro yes, i took it from vector spaces.
My problem is that I'm not used to consider morphism so I don't honestly quite undestand how they works.
Anyway I'll try to give you some more context because I'm getting some answer that I fear could lead me astray.

Comment: are you requiring that the map be a continuous surjection from $S^2\to S^2$ or just a surjection?

Comment: What about $f(z)= z^n$ on $S^1$?

Comment: @CSquared since it's a morphism between topological space it has to be continuos.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma honestly I don't know how make that function work since my spheres are defined in real spaces. I've only used the map $z\mapsto z^2$ on S^1 where S^1 is the complex unit disc

Comment: The complex circle is still a subset of the plane and these maps are perfectly fine “real” maps.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma well if I have to bring them over the real plane the only way I can immagine is to consider them as rotation,and since I'm working on $S^2$ they have fixed point.

Comment: "Real space" is a meaningless concept.

Comment: @MoisheKohan sorry but that's a language problem. In my native language we often use real space to talk about space whose coefficient are inside $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Barbamento And this would be meaningless, regardless of your native language.

Comment: @MoisheKohan man, I'm here because I don't understand things. If you want to be helpfull, help me understand, do not just state the ovious fact that I misunderstood things. I (and I think everyone else here) already knew that

Comment: The example I gave is surjective and not injective.

Comment: So, I am pointing to one source of your misconception that you should correct before you can solve problems like the one you posted: You are confusing the *vector spaces* (for which the adjective real/complex, and the notion of kernel make sense) and *topological spaces* for which these adjectives and the notion of kernel does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the polynomial $p(z)=(z+i)(z-1)$ from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ equpped with the usual topology.  All non-constant polynomials are surjective, as an almost direct consequence of the fundamental theorem of algebra, and $p$ is clearly not injective, since $p(-i)=p(1)=0$ and $-i\neq 1$.

As of the edit, just consider the graphs of some polynomials of degree three from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I forgot to said that but right now I'm sticking to space with real coefficient. I'll edit the post immediately